# Autoresize subviews when the frame of superview is modified

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a green rectangle (viewA) with a inner red rectangle (viewB). If I try to modify the dimension of the viewA the viewB is not automatically changed.

I try to:

- check the autoresizesSubviews value (is true)
- set an autoresizingMask
- change the bounds instead the frame of the superview

All these solution don't work.

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewA: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    viewA.autoresizesSubviews = true
    self.viewA.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight,.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
    viewA.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100) // or frame instead of bounds
}
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks to everyone.

**EDIT:**

I add the two views in the storyboard. Here you can see also the constraint of the viewB.

[image]

Comment: you need to change your viewB. bounds also , else show the code how will you added the subview to viewA

Comment: show the view hierarchy of ViewA & viewB

Comment: Don’t use auto resizing mask. Just add auto layout constraints to the views in interface builders. Then you don’t need any code.

Comment: Make sure the button is the subview of viewA, and, then you are changing the bounds of viewA. The bounds of the button is dependent of viewA.

Comment: I added the two views in the storyboard and put some constraints base on the bounds of the superview but it doesn't work. (see the edit in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't mix up frame and auto layout of a view, both are behaving differently.**

You need to do something like as follow.

> Constrains for viewA

- CenterX and CenterY
- (Height or Width) and Aspect Ratio 1:1 (means equal width and equal height)

> Constraints for viewB

- Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom to its superview (i.e. viewA)

Now you need to Create an `@IBOutlet` to the constraint you need to modify(of viewA).

```
@IBOutlet weak var const_height_viewA: NSLayoutConstraints!
```

So on button click you need to change only constraint's constant.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    const_height_viewA.constant = 250
    //changing height constraint of viewA will automatically updates viewB frame.
}
```

**Note: No need to modify constraints of viewB as it will be automatically adjusted by given constraints.**

For pictorial reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the frame if you are using AutoLayout. If you are using AutoLayout, it is best to update the constraints to the values you want instead of changing the frame.

Notice the first point in the Rule of Thumb section from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1).